# Meteor require login for all pages and redirect to login if not loggingIn iron:router

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-accounts

I have a question, i want to do an app web where all pages require a login authentification (like facebook), but i don't find how to redirect my user to the home page when he is logging in. And when i want to force him to go to the login page.
I'm using iron:router, account:login and coffeescript

Thank you in advance

```js
OnBeforeActions = loginRequired: () ->
    if !Meteor.user()
        if Meteor.loggingIn()

        else
            Router.go 'login'
    else
        Router.go 'home'

Router.onBeforeAction OnBeforeActions.loginRequired, only: [
    'home'
    'models'
    'photographers'
    'createProfil'
    'createProject'
]

Router.route '/login', (-> 
    @render 'login'),
    name: 'login',
    layoutTemplate: 'loginLayout'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your hook you need to check if the user is logged in, if they aren't then you redirect the router to the login page and stop the current route from loading.  If they are then you continue loading the current route.  I would also suggest using `except:` instead of `only:` if you want this hook to run on every page except `login`.

Here's a javascript equivalent to what you need to do (which I know works):

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function () {    
    if  (!Meteor.userId() && !Meteor.loggingIn()) {
        this.redirect('login');
        this.stop();
    } else {
        this.next();
    }
},{except: ['login'] });
```

and in coffeescript (which I have not tested since I don't use coffeescript myself):

```
Router.onBeforeAction (->
  if !Meteor.userId() and !Meteor.loggingIn()
    @redirect 'login'
    @stop()
  else
    @next()
  return
), except: [ 'login' ]
```

To redirect a user after login you add an `onLogin` hook.

```
Accounts.onLogin(function () {
    Router.go('home');
})
```

Again, in coffee (untested):

```
Accounts.onLogin ->
  Router.go 'home'
  return
```

Comment: Thanks it is redirecting when i m not login in but when i'm login in i stay on the login page

Comment: To be redirected after login you need to add an onLogin hook.  Redirecting a logged in user away from the login page is something else

Answer (score 0):

The following function will check whether a user is logged in. If not, it will check whether he/she is currently logging in. If both cases are false I will direct the user to the route with the name 'login'.

```
loginRequired = function () {
    if (!Meteor.user()) {
        if (!Meteor.loggingIn()) {
            this.render('login');
        }
    } else {
        this.next();
    }
};

Router.onBeforeAction(loginRequired, {except: 'login'});
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer!